# trouble with featured image

Tags: images

I don't understand why this happens

I created a new image size in functions.php called blog. Code looks like this

```
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size('blog', 134, 134, false);
```

Yet for some reason when the featured image comes out as 134 by 58 when called like this

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('blog'); ?>
```

Can anyone tell me why that is? The actual image uploaded to the library is much larger than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set that final argument of `add_image_size()` to `false`, it scales the image down until the height or width matches one of the set values, then it maintains the proportions.

For example:

- A 600px by 400px image using your settings is 134px wide (the long dimension) and then 89px tall (proportional to 134px wide).
- If the image were 400px by 600px it would be 134px tall by 89px wide.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but why didn't it change when I changed it to true? The image is big enough

Comment: If you change `add_image_size()` parameters after the fact, you often have to use a plugin like Regenerate Thumbnails to recrop all the photos.